# How do I make a class variable automatically available to its children classes?

Tags: php

I have an `Application` class and I also have a number of separate classes that extend it. If I set a `$variable` in the parent `Application` class, How do I make it automatically available in its children?

```
class Application {
    public $variable;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->variable = "Something";
    }
}

class Child extends Application {
  public function doSomthing() {
    $mything = $variable." is cool";
    return $mything;
  }
}
```

I know I can put `global $variable;` in my `doSomthing()` method, but that is super tedious to do over and over in every method I write. Is there a way to do it where it just is available to all my child class methods?
Thanks.

Comment: Just use `$this->variable`

Comment: Have you try the parent declaration?
[parent::](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set a property named `variable` in your `Application` class in [`__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) method.

If the property [visibility permits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) (e.g. is public or protected), you can access a property `potato` in any children classes method with `$this->potato`:

```
class Application {
    public $variable;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->variable = "Something";
    }
}

class Child extends Application {
  public function doSomthing() {
    $mything = $this->variable." is cool";
    return $mything;
  }
}
```